# How to configure Codeblocks to highlight lines when debugging?

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

I looked for an answer here on stack and bing but didn't find anything that fits my case. There it.

My problem is that I installed code blocks recently and I'm not very familiar with it, and I noticed
that when debugging everything goes fine, I can set breakpoints and  watch variables, but it gives me no idea of which line it is executing (doesn't highlight them).